# bash replaces new lines with space when using tr and assigning to a variable

Tags: bash

I'd like to replace commas with new lines and assign it to a variable. The result of tr is in this case does the job:

```
$echo "a,b" | tr ',' '\n'
a
b
```

However using the same command and assigning it to a variable changes new lines to spaces:

```
$ x=$(echo "a,b" | tr ',' '\n')
$ echo $x
a b
```

How to make it work so in the final result there are new lines not converted to spaces?

Comment: Quote it as `echo "$x"`

Comment: The problem is with `echo` . Try echo "$x"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should put the variable inside double quotes as the argument to `echo` and may use the `-e` option of the echo than enables the interpretation of escape sequences (default behavior in many cases).

```
x=$(echo "a,b" | tr ',' '\n')
echo -e "$x"
```

But you have more elegant way to do the same, consider parameter expansion like below :

```
var="a,b"
echo -e "${var/,/\\n}"
```